# Angular 4 + Laravel 5 Erro: The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable

Tags: php, laravel-5, angular-routes, angular, microsoft-azure

Tenho um projeto em que estou utilizando Angular 4 e Laravel 5.

Localmente ele está funcionando localmente porém quando subo em produção (estou utilizando o Azure como servidor) não funciona corretamente.

Tenho um formulário de cadastro e o Angular. E ao clicar no botão de "cadastrar" é executado esse método:

```
onSubmit(form){
    console.log(form.value);
    this.http.post('/api/register', (form.value))
        .map(dados => dados)
        .subscribe(dados => console.log(dados));
  }
```

Esse método envia os dados para a rota da api do Laravel (api.php):

```
Route::post('/register', 'UserController@store');
```

Localmente, quando rodo a aplicação via comando "php artisan serve", ela funciona perfeitamente. Porém quando subi em produção, o console me reportou esse erro quando cliquei o botão "cadastrar":

"The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."

Ele está tentando acessar a URL /api/register porém essa url não existe realmente.

Localmente ele reconhece, mas em produção não funciona.
Como posso resolver ou contornar esse erro?

Comment: Você já reiniciou o Aplicativo Azure ?

Comment: Ainda não. Irei reiniciar para ver

Comment: Reiniciei e não adiantou..

Comment: Essa foi uma tentativa que encontrei aqui no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34727806/)

Comment: Veja se isso pode te ajudar [laracasts](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/tips/how-to-host-vue-js-app-in-iis)

Comment: Eu inseri o web.config na pasta wwwroot e reiniciei a aplicação. Porém não funcionou..

Comment: Tentei fazer como a pessoa explicou em: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36962678/use-laravel-on-azure-webapp mas também não funcionou. Estou inserindo o web.config na pasta errada?